# PHP Webservice not being consumed

Tags: php, web-services

I'm using nusoap and I'm having dificulties in consuming webservices ... What I'm trying to return to who consumes one of the webservices is one array ...
In the first case I'm trying to return this type of array:

```
Array ( [0] => EX123EX [1] => Test [2] => 2013/04/27 [3] => 12:06 [4] => This is a test [5] => [+]Info [-]Info )
```

And for this I have:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'details',
'complexType',
'struct',
'all',
'',
array(
        'id' => array('name' => 'id', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'product' => array('name' => 'product', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'date' => array('name' => 'date', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'hour' => array('name' => 'hour', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'status' => array('name' => 'status', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
    'info' => array('name' => 'info', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
));

$server->register(
'getdetails',
array('url' => 'xsd:string'),
array('return' => 'tns:details'),
            $namespace,
            false,
            'rpc',
            'literal',
            'details');
```

and the function:

```
function getdetalhes($url)
{
$details = getHeader($url);
return $details;
}
```

The problem is that the webservice is not consumed... When I make the request I have no answer ... With this error I'm also unable to keep on for the next webservice that would return an array with this structure:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2012/12/13 [1] => 12:06 [2] => Test [3] => - [4] => Test Test  [5] => Test ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 2012/12/13 [1] => 09:23 [2] => Test Test  [3] => - [4] => Test  [5] => - ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 2012/12/12 [1] => 17:43 [2] => Test  [3] => - [4] => Test  [5] => - ) [4] => Array ( [0] => 2012/12/12 [1] => 11:25 [2] => Test  [3] => Test  [4] =>Test [5] => - )
```

I'm confident that the error is on the complexType declaration but I can't figure out what is the problem, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, make sure that you're accessing the associative keywords of the array instead of indexes :)

Comment: Wow! It really helped a lot mate! Thank you!! :) Can you advise me on passing an array inside the main array? It should be like 'date' => array( array ('name' => 'date', 'type' => 'xsd:string')), ? or there is something more to it ?

Comment: You're welcome! Answering u're question, I think that complex types would be very helpfull. First, you create a complex type with your data structure (f.e.: car -> id, trademark, model, code, etc.) and then you will have to create another one holding an array of cars. The following example can show you a simple tutorial to retrieve an array of email contacts: http://www.koopman.me/2008/01/nusoap-wsdl-service-return-array-of-complex-data/